# Boolean logic gate implementation

Tags: logic

how many minimum number of nand gate is required to implement f=A+B'C ?  please give a diagram so i can understand... In general what is strategy to implement logic with minimum number of nand gate?

Answer (score 1):

I will not provide a diagram because I don't have software to produce such. However the implementation of logic circuitry (non-state-machine) is the same as providing an boolean expression for it.

Given the requirement to just minimize the number of NAND gates you would use conjunctive normal form. In fact your expression is already on that form.

However conjunctive normal form expresses it as a conjunction of disjunctions (ie ORing together ANDs), but we want to express it as NANDs of NANDs. It turns out that you could do that transformation by using only nands due to DeMorgan law:

$$f = A+\overline B C = \overline{\overline{A+\overline B C}}=\overline{\overline A \cdot \overline {\overline B\cdot C}}$$

Now if we use $\overline\cdot$ as symbol for NAND (ie $x\overline\cdot y = \overline{x\cdot y}$ this becomes:

$$f = \overline A \overline\cdot (\overline{\overline B\cdot C)} = \overline A \overline\cdot(\overline B \overline\cdot C)$$

The rule is that using conjunctive normal form you would get a circuit containing first a layer of NOT gates followed by AND gates followed by an OR gate (or multiple OR gates if you have multiple outputs). The rule here is that you simply replace all AND and OR gates with NAND gates with that exception that signals that go from the NOT gate layer directly to the OR gate layer has to be inverted.

So in general the strategy is to bring the expression to (minimal) conjunctive normal form. This is normally done using Karnaugh diagrams if you're human and there's only few enough variables. Otherwise you may use formal algorithms (that is basically the same as Kaurnaugh diagrams expressed in a more algorithmic way).

Comment: I think according to your method answer is 4 ....

Comment: Yes, if you count NOT-gates.

Comment: How do you show that 4 is the minimal number of gates?

Comment: @copper.hat In this particular case you use that the disjunctive normal form is the minimal disjunctive normal form and if you don't use disjunctive normal form you'd need more than two layers (the initial NOT not counted). The only hope lies at a circuit of three layers and those should be possible to check. Otherwise in general using the disjunctive normal form to get a minimal circuit I guess is more a rule of the thumb.